# Modifying fullcalendar to divide day time based on users

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm currently working on a front end calendar. I'm using jQuery, **[fullcalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io/)** and **bootstrap**. Recently I came across a design and now i'm trying to **implement it using the fullcalendar**.

**Design:** I want to show time for day on left side of the calendar and on the top I want to show all the users column by column. I also want to remaining features of the calendar like adding events, draggable etc

Below I have added the pic showing the design:

[image]

**Is there any way I can create a calendar similar to the one shown above using the fullcalendar.io ?**

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [vertical resource view](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical_resource_view/getting_started/) from the scheduler plugin ? It looks exactly like what you need.